# Uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error> from boost inside Android app

Tags: android, c++, boost, java-native-interface, sigabrt

I'm using boost inide an android app and getting a random SIGABRT:

```
    "terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>: partial message" failed'
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.643 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 0000600f  ecx 00006057  edx 00000006
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.643 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     esi 85c46978  edi 85c46920
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.643 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.643 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     eip aa5d1424  ebp 85c42918  esp 85c428bc  flags 00000296
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.644 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.644 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc ffffe424  [vdso:aa5d1000] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.644 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0007a03c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+28)
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.644 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00075885  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+85)
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.644 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0002785a  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+42)
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.645 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0001ee36  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+86)
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.645 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00023d48  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+40)
    2020-06-30 17:44:52.645 24683-24683/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0001f300  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+64)
```

I'm running the Android emulator so this is happening on X86 cpu, but I can't tell more than that,
ASM is really obscure to me. Code doesn't seem complicated.
This is the CPP file called from JNI:

```
HttpClient syncclient(io_service);
syncclient.getJsonSync();   <---SIGABRT
```

And getJsonSync does this:

```
getJsonSync(){
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    beast::tcp_stream stream(io_service);

    auto const results = resolver.resolve(server, port);

    stream.connect(results);
    http::request<http::string_body> req{http::verb::post, path, 11};

    req.set(http::field::host, server);
    req.version(11);
    req.set(http::field::authorization, authorization);
    req.set(beast::http::field::content_type, "application/json");
    req.set(beast::http::field::connection, "close");
    req.body() = data;
    req.prepare_payload();

    http::write(stream, req);
    beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;
    http::read(stream, buffer, res);

    Response *nr = NULL; //structure where msg body and http status code are copied
    if (res.result_int() == 200*){
        std::string body { boost::asio::buffers_begin(res.body().data()),
                           boost::asio::buffers_end(res.body().data()) };

        initNativeResponse(&nr, id); //alloc the structure

        if(nr == NULL){
            /* memory allocation failed */
            return NULL;
        }
        nr->obj = strdup(body.c_str());
        nr->msg_code =res.result_int();
    }

    beast::error_code ec;
    stream.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

    if (ec && ec != beast::errc::not_connected){
        return NULL;
    }
    return nr;
}
```

and initNativeResponse not very informative but I add it here:

```
void initNativeResponse(Response **response, int msgId){
*response = (Response *) malloc(sizeof(struct native_response));
if(*response == NULL){
    return;
}
(*response)->id = msgId;
(*response)->obj = NULL;

}
```

Comment: Well, can any of the Boost functions you're using throw exceptions? If so, you need to handle them somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Crashes aren't random.

Especially not if they're from uncaught exceptions (then they're from failure to handle exceptions).

And usually the exception is a good indication of what the problem is. In your case:

boost::system::system_error: partial message

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket/send_and_receive_messages.html

That's your problem. The parser didn't receive a full message. Many reasons exist. If the connection is closed midway the response, that would be natural.

Reading your code

```
    std::string body{ boost::asio::buffers_begin(res.body().data()),
                      boost::asio::buffers_end(res.body().data()) };
```

makes me think that you should just use a `string_body` to begin with.

### ASIDE

> initNativeResponse not very informative but I add it here:

Not informative. It was the most amotiquated bit of C abuse I've seen in a long while. Same for `strdup`. `strdup` makes it not a POD anyways.

Here's a c++ write of it:

```
struct Response {
    int id;
    int msg_code;
    char* obj = nullptr;

    ~Response() {
        ::free(static_cast<void*>(obj));
        obj = nullptr;
    }
};

using ResponsePtr = std::unique_ptr<Response>;

ResponsePtr initNativeResponse(int msgId) {
    return std::make_unique<Response>(Response{ msgId, 0, nullptr });
}
```

Although, really, you would be better of just using value-semantics:

```
struct Response {
    int id;
    int msg_code = 0;
    std::string obj;
};
```

Now you can just write:

```
return Response{id, res.result_int(), std::move(res.body())};
```

And it will be exception safe, more allocation optimized etc. If you really must indicate "no response" (why? that would only happen if malloc failed... exception territory), use `std::optional<Response>`.

### Demo Code

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c464d6a56bac696b)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <memory>

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
auto constexpr server = "example.com";
auto constexpr port = "http";
auto constexpr path = "/";
auto constexpr authorization = "dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==";
auto constexpr data = R"({ "some" : 42, "data": { "nested": [1,2,3], "fields" : null } })";

struct Response {
    int id;
    unsigned msg_code = 0;
    std::string obj;
};

static inline auto make_request() {
    http::request<http::string_body> req{ http::verb::post, path, 11 };

    req.set(http::field::host, server);
    req.version(11);
    req.set(http::field::authorization, authorization);
    req.set(beast::http::field::content_type, "application/json");
    req.set(beast::http::field::connection, "close");
    req.body() = data;
    req.prepare_payload();
    return req;
}

Response getJsonSync() {
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    beast::tcp_stream stream(io_service);

    auto results = resolver.resolve(server, port);

    stream.connect(results);

    http::write(stream, make_request());
    beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    http::response<http::string_body> res;
    http::read(stream, buffer, res);

    if (res.result_int() == 200) {
        stream.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both); // exception handling FTW

        int id = 42; // FIXME
        return { id, res.result_int(), std::move(res.body()) };
    }

    return {};
}

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    auto res = getJsonSync();
    std::cout << "res.id: " << res.id << "\n";
    std::cout << "res.msg_code: " << res.msg_code << "\n";
    std::cout << "res.obj: " << std::quoted(res.obj) << "\n";
}
```

Prints (given network access):

```
res.id: 42
res.msg_code: 200
res.obj: "<!doctype html>
<html>

     [... snip ...]

</html>
"
```